# How to make two models related to each other(vice versa) in django. one company should have mutiple catalog but one catalog can have only one company

Tags: python, django

```
class Catalog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    no_of_pcs = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    per_piece_price = models.DecimalField(null=True,blank=True,max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    catalog = models.ManyToManyField(Catalog)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name`***
```

Comment: It is called a ForeignKey. I suggest you to follow a Django tutorial before actually implementing a project.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a substitute for reading the FineManual

Answer (score 1):

The basic [models documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/) has a lot of info you'll need to know (including [what you're asking for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships)) and the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/) should put you through the fundamentals. Django's doc in general is pretty good, and the source is reasonably readable, so right there you have two great resources in addition to SO.